# ValueError: too many values to unpack when using socket

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, google-app-engine

```
import socket
import time
HOST = "192.168.x.x"
PORT = 5454
data = "Hello"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(HOST,PORT)
while  True:
   s.sendto(data(HOST,PORT))
   print "send" + data
   time.sleep(1)
```

I am gettting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~lyfe-playtm/20161117t121204.397114004363270281/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    s.connect(HOST,PORT)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 222, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 752, in connect
    address_hostname_hint=_hostname_hint)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 590, in _CreateSocket
    address_hostname_hint)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 632, in _SetProtoFromAddr
    address, port = address
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I am trying to use socket in Google App Engine. This is the code i put in my `main.py` . How do i get rid of this error?

Comment: You aren't showing the code that is causing this error. But it looks like `address` is not a 2-tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [17.2. socket — Low-level networking interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html):

> Socket addresses are represented as follows: ... A pair (host, port)
>   is used for the AF_INET address family, where host is a string
>   representing either a hostname in Internet domain notation like
>   'daring.cwi.nl' or an IPv4 address like '100.50.200.5', and port is an
>   integer.

and

> socket.**connect**(address)
>
> Connect to a remote socket at address. (The format of address depends
>   on the address family — see above.)
>
> ```
> Note
>
> This method has historically accepted a pair of parameters for AF_INET addresses instead of only a tuple. This was never intentional
> ```
>
> and is no longer available in Python 2.0 and later.

Which means you should change

```
s.connect(HOST,PORT)
```

with

```
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
```

Similarly below change

```
   s.sendto(data(HOST,PORT))
```

with

```
   s.sendto(data, (HOST,PORT))
```

**Side note:** when using `s.sendto()` the socket should **not** be connected (either drop the `s.connect()` or use `s.send()` or `s.sendall()`):

> socket.sendto(string, address) socket.sendto(string, flags, address)
>
> Send data to the socket. The socket should not be connected to a
>   remote socket, since the destination socket is specified by address.
>   The optional flags argument has the same meaning as for recv() above.
>   Return the number of bytes sent. (The format of address depends on the
>   address family — see above.)